# Queue up requests to a sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking, deadlock, isolation-level

I am working with a stored procedure that:

1. determines the number of rows in the table where the chosenBy column is null
2. picks one of these rows at random
3. updates the chosenBy column of this row
4. returns the row to the client

How do I prevent clients from choosing the same row in situations where they choose at exactly the same time?

I have tried various table hints and isolation levels but just get deadlock exceptions at the client. I just want the second call to wait for the fraction of a second until the first call is completed.

Comment: Essentially you are [using a table as a queue](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) but does it *really* need to be random as that adds to the problem considerably.

Comment: As long as it appears to be relatively random (i.e. it is not sequential) then that is sufficient.

Comment: What about a solution that just serialises access to the stored procedure using `sp_getapplock` rather than attempting to manage concurrency and avoid deadlocks?

Comment: Not familiar with that but after looking at MSDN, do you mean that I call that in my client code. i.e. acquire the lock. if sucessful execute sproc, otherwise wait and try again or is it more automatic?

Comment: You put it in the stored proc itself then `sp_releaseapplock` at the end of the code to serialize access to that bit of code. Means you won't get deadlocks but might get waits and timeouts instead dependant upon how long the code takes to run and how often concurrent attempts occur.

Comment: Fantastic. That seems to be working perfectly. If you put that in an answer, I'll mark it as accepted and vote it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of avoiding deadlocks (as indicated in your question title) would be to serialise access to that procedure.

You can do this with [`sp_getapplock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) and `sp_releaseapplock`

See [Application Locks (or Mutexes) in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/application-locks-or-mutexes-in-sql-server-2005) for some example code.